# What does SCSI LUN id mean and what is its use?

Tags: linux, ioctl, scsi

In Linux what does the LUN id mean in ioctl SCSI_IOCTL_GET_LUNID? And what does the signify? How will it help?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Unit_Number

Answer (score 0):

LUN id is the Logical Unit Number, and refers to a storage device.

From the Wikipedia article tMC linked in his comment:

> LUN 0: There is one LUN which is required to exist in every target:
>   zero. The logical unit with LUN zero is special in that it must
>   implement a few specific commands, most notably Report LUNs, which is
>   how an initiator can find out all the other LUNs in the target. But
>   LUN zero need not provide any other services, such as a storage
>   volume.

So each target has a LUN 0. A target could have further LUNs if it had further storage volumes.

Comment: Thank you Almo. I am using a tool that displays all the LUNs exposed to the host. Along with the Device file name and LUN size it displays the target Id and LUN Id.  I understand the use of LUN size. What I understand from target Id is that each SCSI bus can have multiple SCSI devices connected to it. On SCSI parallel buses the number of ids is related to the width. 8 bit buses can have 8 SCSI ids. Target Id is the the bus used by the target. Now what is a LUN Id? I am asking this because I see all the LUNs have Lun Id 0.

Comment: Thanks Again Almo! I do know about LUN 0 but all the LUNs I have exposed to my hosts can't be LUN 0s. They are exposed as storage volumes. It would be great if you can give me at least one use case of LUN Id. I mean what as an end user or Storage Administrator I can do with LUN Id and if possible target Id too.

Comment: It's up to the hardware. I thought that you could have a box that would be a target, and it might internally have a hard drive with two partitions, and each partition might have a different LUN. I could be wrong about that, as it's been years since I worked with SCSI. I suspect in your case that it's not needed.

Comment: Thank you Almo. Will see if anyone else has any other view on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly speaking, you can consider every logical unit (identified by lun) represents a successive logical blocks, numbered from 0. So if SCSI initiator intends to access SCSI target, it must offer target ID, LUN, offset of logical block and how many blocks it wants.